# laravel queries in custom file after sending ajax in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have created an ajax.php file on my server and send id to the file using ajax with jquery.

I want to run db queries in that ajax.php file to get the result.

I am unable to do this.

Can you please help me.

Jquery Code:

```
$('.invitebyemail').click(function(){
    var email = $('#add-members-event-email').val();
    var eventid = $('.eventid').val();
    var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
    var url      = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL
    var APP_URL = {!! json_encode(url('/')) !!};
    alert(APP_URL);
    alert(url);
    $.ajax({
        url: APP_URL+'/ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',    
        data: { id: eventid },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Ajax File Code:

```
use DB;
$eventid = $_POST['id'];
echo $eventid;
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
print_r($users);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the path where you saved the ajax.php?

Comment: The file is in public folder.@SérgioReis, The ajax file is working fine but I am trying to use sql queries in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using laravel I don't belive that using .php files like that would be the correct way of doing it... it's not really following the MVC patterns.

I recomend creating a controler `php artisan make:controller MyController`
creating a function as this on the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Session;
use Auth;
use Response;
use DB;
use App\User;

class MyController extends Controller{
  public function getUsers(Request $request){
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
    // If you need access to request parameters use this ( $request->id ) being id the parameter name 
    return response()->json(["users" =>$users]);
  }

}
```

creating a route in ProjectFolder/routes/web.php like this

```
Route::post('/getUsersAjax',[
  'uses'=>'MyController@getUsers',
  'as'=>'getUsers'
]);
```

And in your jquery dont forget to add the _token to your data `data: { id: eventid , _token : token},`
(if you need this token you can in a .blade.php file, your view, make this

```
<script>
   var token = "{{Session::token()}}";
   var urlRequest = "{{route('getUsers')}}";
</script>
```

)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing

Comment: Thanks, I was trying this way also. But I am stuck at some point so I am trying the other way to get result. Any ways thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you help me here also. I want to submit the form to usercontroller file and call function invitebyemail.

When I click on submit it gives me error like "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Below are the structure of my Files and code.

Route File:
  
    Route::POST('event/inviteforevent', 'UserController@invitebyemail');

Blade.php file

    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'event/inviteforevent')) }}
 <input type="submit" name="invite" value="submit" />
 {{ Form::close() }}

Comment: Not really used to use form, but if i was doing that, my form would be like this, 
(named route
Route::post('/event/inviteforevent'',[
  'uses'=>'MyController@invitebyemail',
  'as'=>'invitebyemail'
]);
)

<form action="{{route('invitebyemail')}} method="POST"> 
<!-- normal stuff here -->
</form>

Comment: I prefer using named routes all the way since that way i dont really need to care about making sure all urls dont have a typo

Comment: <form action="{{route('event/inviteforevent')}}" method="POST"><input type="submit" name="invite" value="submit" /></form>, Is it is working or not. It gives me error when I try to load the page.

Comment: {{route('event/inviteforevent')}} doesn't work unless you have a route that is named "inviteforevent" Check here for reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes

Comment: It should like this ? Route::get('event/inviteforevent', 'UserController@invitebyemail')->name('inviteforevent');
//Route::post('event/inviteforevent', 'UserController@invitebyemail');

Comment: Yes, that way when you route route('inviteforevent') laravel builds the URL for you btw, you're using POST in the form, the route needs to be post, for example Route::post('event/inviteforevent', 'UserController@invitebyemail')->name('inviteforevent');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145704/discussion-between-gaurav-sharna-and-sergio-reis).